# How to iterate a queryset and append to a string

Tags: python, django

I have the following function in my view to generate notifications whenever a user has been removed from a project :

```
            for user in project.userProfile.all():
             Notifications.objects.create(
                            target=user.user,
                            extra='Users',
                            object_url='',
                            title='The following users have been removed : ' + str(removed_users)  ,
                        )
```

Of which `removed_users` is a queryset containing my `UserProfile` model. What i wish to accomplish is to be able to iterate through the queryset `removed_users` , access the `username` field which belongs to the default `django auth` model , and append it to the string in title

Is there a clean easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `', '.join(…)` for example:

```
for user in project.userProfile.all():
    Notifications.objects.create(
        target=user.user,
        extra='Users',
        object_url='',
        title='The following users have been removed : {}'.format(
            ', '.join(str(u) for u in removed_users)
        ),
    )
```